# Internet Explorer Mode in Microsoft Edge in Windows 11

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, activex

Some of our applications heavily depend on the ActiveX controls. As Microsoft discontinued support for Internet Explorer, we give a try for Microsoft Edge.

- Solution 1 : Using Microsoft Edge -> Settings -> Default browser

This method works fine. But the added links will expire within 30 days. I have about 25 links, so every month I have to re-add ( the expiry can be adjusted to 90 days)

- Solution 2 : Using Enterprise Site List configured in Group Policy

We have tried as in the below link but it is not working. We also tried in a standalone PC which is not connected to our domain.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies

After trying Solution 2 and could not succeed we have reverted all the adjustment done. But now the solution 1 itself is not working. After adding the link to "Internet Explorer mode pages" and restarting the Edge browser, the link is cleared.

So what is the best option to use Internet Explorer in Microsoft Edge in Windows 11.

Comment: I think you should rather ask why Solution 2 went wrong. Otherwise, there is also [Solution 3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list).

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the "Solution 3". This one and Solution 1 are the same. As you suggested, I was too interested to know why the Solution 2 is not working. But where from I can get the details ( like if one installed software is not working, we can check Event Viewer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use **[this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72597795/15764378)** to modify your IE Mode page entries in the Edge **Preferences** file so that they expire far in the future (by default, the script sets the date added to 2099 which makes the expiry also 2099).